# SPARQL filter results dates only

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to find all results that are dates, regardless of the properties they're describing. This FILTER query gives me the results I want:

```
PREFIX mydb: <http://mydb.org/schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?s ?p ?date 
WHERE { 
?s ?p ?date .
FILTER (?date > "1800-01-01"^^xsd:date)
}
```

But it only works because I set a bottom limit earlier than my earliest date. Is there a way to use a boolean filter for the `xsd:date` datatype, similar to `isURI()`?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-datatype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILTER ( datatype(?date) = xsd:date )` is the filter I needed.

Thanks to [Stanislav Kralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin) for his comment.